# What is the derivative of this quadratic form?

Tags: derivatives, quadratic-forms

Given the quadratic form
$f(x)=x^TK(x)x $, what is its derivative ? Thanks in advance.
Edit : using Golden_Ratio suggestion I get :
$ f’(x) = (K(x)+K^T(x))x+2K’(x)x^TK(x)$
. Is it correct?

Comment: That's not a quadratic form if $K(x)$ is not constant

Comment: Try using scalar-by-vector product rule identity [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-vector_identities)